# Android to apk via Buildozer: Play Sound with pygame - Kivy

Tags: python, android, audio, kivy, buildozer

I have an desktop app made with Kivy that plays wav files using pygame all is well.

When I convert it to apk via buildozer I get an error like:
pygame.error: Unable to open file '/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/a.wav',
It first crashes pushing the play button.

What I already tried or checked:

- I use the same version of pygame and Kivy in android and on my desktop(pycharm):
  pycharm: 2.1.0 (Pycharm and Buildozer), Kivy: also 2.1.0 (Pycharm and Buildozer)
- I use a different python version: on my dekstop: 3.10 and on android 3.8.9
- I use wavs with 16 bit p sample and a sample rate of 44.1 or 48 kHz (tried both)
- I get the path on android of my wav file for pygame via: os.getcwd() so I should get             the right path, I also tried the hard copy one (/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/)
- I also tried pygames mixer.music or mixer.sound and its pre inits, again all worked              on my desktop
- of course I use pygame in my buildozer requirements

Before I used kivy's own Soundloader, but in the end I don't want to just play and stop music, I want to pause and unpause it, meaning I need the seek function, that only works with ffpyplayer. When I use ffpyplayer=4.3.5 it works on my desktop,
but this version is not available on python for android, only ffpyplayer==4.3.2 which could be the problem.

At the end I am deeply disappointed that all my hard work in Kivy doesn't payoff because of the buildozer process...I really read all stack overflows, I am on discord nothing...
Please help me out, really I need your help, thank you so much.

My Kivy code:

```
import os 
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import  Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from pygame import mixer 



 class Screen1(Screen):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):

    super().__init__(**kwargs)

    self.floatlayout = FloatLayout()
    self.add_widget(self.floatlayout)
    self.icon = Label(text="you did it!")
    self.icon.opacity = 0
    self.icon.size_hint = (1,1)
    self.icon.md_bg_color = (0,0,0,0)
    self.icon.color = (0,0,0,1)
    self.icon.pos_hint = {"center_x":2, "center_y":0.35}
    self.icon.type = "small"
    self.icon.width = 1000
    self.icon.text_size = 250/360 * Window.size[0], 600 * Window.size[1]/600
    self.icon.halign = "center"
    self.icon.valign = "top"
    self.icon.font_size = 35
    self.icon.background_down = ""
    self.icon.background_normal = ""

    self.icon2 = Button(text="")
    self.icon2.size_hint = (1,1)
    self.icon2.md_bg_color = (1,0,1,1)

    self.background_img = Image(source=path_main + "1__.png",
                                allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False)

    self.but = Button(on_press = self.push)
    self.but.text = "Affirmationen"
    self.but.font_name = path_main + 'AlexBrush-Regular.ttf'
    self.but.size_hint = (0.3,0.3)

    self.s = Button(on_press = self.stop)
    self.s.text = "stop"
    self.s.size_hint = (0.2,0.2)
    self.s.pos_hint = {"center_y": 0.9}

    self.but2 = Button(text="1")
    self.but2.size_hint = (0.1,0.1)
    self.but2.pos_hint = {"center_x" : 0.5}

    self.but3 = Button(text = "play_music", on_press = self.play)
    self.but3.size_hint = (0.1,0.1)
    self.but3.pos_hint = {"center_x" : 0.5, "center_y" : 0.8}

    self.but4 = Button(text = "pause_music", on_press = self.pause)
    self.but4.size_hint = (0.1,0.1)
    self.but4.pos_hint = {"center_x" : 0.8, "center_y" : 0.9}

    self.but5 = Button(text="unpause_music", on_press=self.unpause)
    self.but5.size_hint = (0.1, 0.1)
    self.but5.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.4, "center_y": 0.4}

    self.floatlayout.add_widget(self.background_img)
    self.floatlayout.add_widget(self.icon)
    self.floatlayout.add_widget(self.but)
    self.floatlayout.add_widget(self.but2)
    self.floatlayout.add_widget(self.but3)
    self.floatlayout.add_widget(self.s)
    self.floatlayout.add_widget(self.but4)
    self.floatlayout.add_widget(self.but5)
    self.i = 2.2

 def push(self, event):
     self.i += 1
     #self.i = np.round(self.i, 0)
     self.but2.text = str(self.i)

 def play(self, event):
     loc = os.getcwd()
     filename = loc + "/a.wav"
     k = os.path.exists(filename)
     if k:
        self.but2.text = filename

     mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096) 
     mixer.init()
     sound_  = mixer.Sound(filename)
     mixer.Sound.play(sound_)


sm = ScreenManager()

class TestApp(MDApp):


  def build(self):
      sm.add_widget(Screen1(name="1"))
      return sm

TestApp().run()
```

My buildozer specs:
[app]

```
# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,ttf,wav

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,pygame

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or     Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 31

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your  app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public  storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be  automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically  downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save  time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to  False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that  implements Android Activity
# use that parameter together with android.entrypoint to set  custom Java class instead of PythonActivity
#android.activity_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest>  element of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load  your custom XML code
#android.extra_manifest_xml = ./src/android/extra_manifest.xml

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest><application> tag of AndroidManifest.xml
 # use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML arguments:
 #android.extra_manifest_application_arguments = ./src/android/extra_manifest_application_arguments.xml

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Python Service
# use that parameter to set custom Java class instead of PythonService
#android.service_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonService

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk assets directory.
# Either form may be used, and assets need not be in 'source.include_exts'.
# 1) android.add_assets = source_asset_relative_path
# 2) android.add_assets = source_asset_path:destination_asset_relative_path
#android.add_assets =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
#android.enable_androidx = False

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the     'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-    dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
android.library_references =

 (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
android.uses_library =

 (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

 (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
android.logcat_pid_only = False

 (str) Android additional adb arguments
android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

 (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
android.copy_libs = 1

 (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a,        arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
 In past, was `android.arch` as we weren't supporting builds   for multiple archs at the same time.
 android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a

 (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in  build.gradle)
 this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
 android.numeric_version = 1

 (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
 android.allow_backup = True

 (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
 android.backup_rules =

 (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
 you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
 This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
 Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
 android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

 (bool) disables the compilation of py to pyc/pyo files when packaging
 android.no-compile-pyo = True

# (str) The format used to package the app for release mode (aab or apk).
# android.release_artifact = aab


# Python for android (p4a) specific


# (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
#p4a.url =

# (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android specific commit to use, defaults to HEAD, must be within p4a.branch
#p4a.commit = HEAD

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false

# (str) extra command line arguments to pass when invoking             pythonforandroid.toolchain
#p4a.extra_args =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) The development team to use for signing the debug version
#ios.codesign.development_team.debug = <hexstring>

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

# (str) The development team to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.development_team.release = <hexstring>

# (str) URL pointing to .ipa file to be installed
# This option should be defined along with `display_image_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.app_url =

# (str) URL pointing to an icon (57x57px) to be displayed during download
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.display_image_url =

# (str) URL pointing to a large icon (512x512px) to be used by iTunes
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `display_image_url`      options.
#ios.manifest.full_size_image_url =


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .aab, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thx for your reply, which part do you mean.i already tried kivy's aoundloader, but the seek function is not avaibale with ffpyplayer or sdl2

Comment: Won't this module work? https://github.com/matham/ffpyplayer

Comment: Yeah, ffpyplayer works on desktop, I have version 4.3.5, but this version doesn't exist for android for python only 4.3.2 and this Doesnt provide the seek function in on my android app after buildozing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote simple test app. In short, you should ask the user for permission to read files, for this you need to specify them in the **buildozer.spec** file and do it using a command in python code.

**main.py**

```py
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy import platform
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher

import pygame.mixer as mixer
import os
import pathlib

if platform == 'android':
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

KV = """
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ProgressBar:
        id: pb
        max: 100
        min: 0
        
    Button:
        text: 'Load'
        on_release: app.load_track()
        
    Button:
        text: 'Play'
        on_release: app.player.play()
        
    Button:
        text: 'Stop'
        on_release: app.player.stop()
        
    Button:
        text: 'Pause'
        on_release: app.player.pause()
        
    Button:
        text: 'Resume'
        on_release: app.player.resume()
        
    Button:
        text: 'Loop'
        on_release: app.player.loop()
"""


class Player(EventDispatcher):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_stop')
        self.register_event_type('on_start')

        self.sound = None
        self.sound_inst = None
        self.song = ''
        self.is_loop = False
        mixer.init()

    def load(self, filename: str):
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            self.song = filename
            mixer.music.load(self.song)
            self.sound_inst = mixer.Sound(self.song)
        else:
            raise FileNotFoundError

    def loop(self):
        if self.is_loop:
            self.is_loop = False
        else:
            self.is_loop = True

    def play(self):
        self.dispatch('on_start')
        mixer.music.play(self.is_loop)

    def stop(self):
        self.dispatch('on_stop')
        mixer.music.stop()

    def pause(self):
        mixer.music.pause()

    def resume(self):
        mixer.music.unpause()

    def get_pos(self):
        return mixer.music.get_pos()

    def get_length(self):
        return self.sound_inst.get_length()  # sec

    def on_stop(self):
        pass

    def on_start(self):
        pass


class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.song = 'test.ogg'  # wav/ogg supported
        self.player = Player()
        self.value_update_clock = None
        self.player.bind(on_stop=lambda inst: (self.cancel_clock(),
                                               Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.set_pb_value(0))
                                               )
                         )
        self.player.bind(on_start=lambda inst: self.set_clock())

    def on_start(self):
        if platform == 'android':
            request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

    def load_track(self):
        filepath = os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent, self.song)
        self.player.load(filepath)
        print(filepath, 'loaded')

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def set_clock(self):
        self.value_update_clock = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.set_pb_value(), 1.0)

    def cancel_clock(self):
        if self.value_update_clock:
            self.value_update_clock.cancel()

    def set_pb_value(self, value: int = None):
        if not value:
            pos = self.player.get_pos() / 1000
            length = self.player.get_length()

            value = round(pos / length * 100, 2)

        self.root.ids.pb.value = value


TestApp().run()
```

**buildozer.spec**

```py
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,mp3,ogg,wav
requirements = kivy, pygame
android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.api = 32
android.minapi = 21
android.ndk = 19c
p4a.branch = master
p4a.bootstrap = sdl2
```

Comment: thx for your answer. I have never used the android permission, that was a good hint here, I thought they are not needed. When I use: mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(filename)
mixer.music.play() the app crashed again. When I use the other code:         mixer.init()
sound_  = mixer.Sound(filename)
mixer.Sound.play(sound_) this the code that really plays the music (the first code that realized that) but I get an really long time lap of 10 secs till the sounds starts. Do you know how to avoid the time lap?

Comment: I tested the code on Windows/Linux/Android. There really is a slight delay on the phone before loading the track, I think you can remove `self.sound_inst = mixer.Sound(self.song)` and use a different method. Otherwise, as for me, everything is OK

Answer (score 1):

Result in short:
I didn't manage to use wav file.
But using a ogg file worked.

At the end of the day I managed to use pygame with mixer.music to play my song as ogg file but not as wav file.
So this is okay for me,there is no delay in the play function and I have the possibility of pause and unpause.
With mixer.sound I can also play wav but there is no possibility to pause and unpause it. Thx to Neizvestnyj to bring in the ogg file.

Comment: You mention that you were able to do it, but you don't mention how for all those who come here after you facing the same struggles. Glad you got a solution worked out though! :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also, why are you not satisfied with my answer?

Comment: Why should I not be satisfied with your answer? I said thx and that it was your impulse. I didn't gave you the green arrow because im new to stack overflow and until now I didn't knew to do it. Is that your problem?

Comment: I don't get you, I clearly said that I now use ogg, that's all... Anything else is exactly the same as in the intro question.